# Node js socket io chat send message notification

Tags: ios, node.js, socket.io

How can we send message notification for ios using node js socket io while the chat app is closed?

Comment: You need to integrate Push notification.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, when a simple message is sent, you will catch it with socket.io and you will send notification via push.js using it.
Push.js: https://pushjs.org/.
It is also explained in detail how it is done on the site.
But if you still want a simple one, here it is:

```
Push.create(data.user_name + " | Chat", {
    body: data.desc,
    icon: "https://pushjs.org/images/icon.png",
    tag: "chat",
    link: "http://localhost:8080/chat",
    timeout: 5000,
    onClick: function () {
         window.focus();
         this.close();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by push notification integration in iOS app.

There are many third parties available which can be integrated into the iOS app and on back end server.

- FCM
- APNS(Apple's native push notification service)
- Pusher
- One Signal, etc.

The above are the some name of the push notification services that can be integrated into app and backend server.

You need to more dig into "How to integrated push notification in iOS app with Node JS backed?" so just google it you will get the may tutorial on the internet.

*Personally saying, we have integrated push in one of your iOS app with Node backed with FCM.*

Answer (score -1):

Fundamentally iOS supports Push Notifications via [APNs (Apple Push Notification service)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1). It’s possible to directly interface with APNs and send messages, however it can often be simpler to instead use a third party service to handle the complexity.

Ably, FCM, PubNub and Pusher are all common solutions which work well in combining an existing messaging system with Push Notifications where needed. If you’re in need of just a notification system, and have no other communication systems, a library for just notifications such as Push.js will work well.